# rbenv doesn't get correct version in tmux

Tags: ruby, tmux, macos-catalina, rbenv

When I in a project folder with file `.ruby-version`, `rbenv version` returns correct ruby version from the project `.ruby-version`, but when I get into tmux,  it always returns the global ruby version.

When I run `RBENV_DEBUG=1 rbenv version`, without tmux, it found the correct local path, it was project path.

```
+ [rbenv-version-file:22] '[' -n '' ']'
+ [rbenv-version-file:25] find_local_version_file /Users/user_name/project_folder
+ [rbenv-version-file:10] local root=/Users/user_name/project_folder
+ [rbenv-version-file:11] [[ /Users/user_name/project_folder =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+ [rbenv-version-file:12] '[' -s /Users/user_name/project_folder/.ruby-version ']'
+ [rbenv-version-file:13] echo /Users/user_name/project_folder/.ruby-version
+ [rbenv-version-file:14] return 0
+ [rbenv-version:11] echo '2.5.7 (set by /Users/user_name/project_folder/.ruby-version)'
```

But in tmux, it got wrong local path, it was home path.

```
+ [rbenv-version-file:7] target_dir=
+ [rbenv-version-file:22] '[' -n '' ']'
+ [rbenv-version-file:25] find_local_version_file /Users/user_name
+ [rbenv-version-file:10] local root=/Users/user_name
+ [rbenv-version-file:11] [[ /Users/user_name =~ ^//[^/]*$ ]]
+ [rbenv-version-file:12] '[' -s /Users/user_name/.ruby-version ']'
+ [rbenv-version-file:13] echo /Users/user_name/.ruby-version
+ [rbenv-version-file:14] return 0
+ [rbenv-version:11] echo '2.5.1 (set by /Users/user_name/.ruby-version)'
```

It worked before upgrading Catalina, It breaks after upgrading Catalina,
So I thought it matter, but I have no idea how to find out, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it doesn't work with tmux, odds are good your environment isn't being sourced correctly.

Comment: @theTinMan Ya, I knew something should be wrong, but It worked before upgrading Catalina, and I ever comment out all the tmux.conf setting, it doesn't help.

Comment: You are probably using `zsh` now rather than `bash`, which uses different configuration files (`.zprofile` instead of `.bash_profile`, `.zshrc` instead of `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 0):

Only work with local ruby version using by rbenv path. The same you have with tmux happens with bundle if your bundle is had been installed previously with a ruby version not managed by rbenv.
Supposing a linux terminal: Inside your tmux, attache your linux terminal and **then** install rbenv according to its [official github repository](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).
If your rbenv was installed after you already have a ruby version installed, tmux might keep searching the global ruby version.